# Sqlserver exec sp_execute to simple query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, profiler

I use sqlserver 2012 profile to watch all query that run on my db.

I saw only `exec sp_execute 2,55,88` or `exec sp_execute 1,43,675`and command like that.

Why I cant watch update/select queries?

Comment: You need to add details to your question.  For instance, what is the trace you are running (script it, then add the T-SQL script to your question)?  What is the exact output from the trace?  Perhaps a screenshot would be helpful?  Also, welcome to StackExchange, please take the [tour] and check the [help].

Answer (score 4):

The application that you are profiling is using prepared statements. The SQL statements are being sent as `sp_prepare @handle OUTPUT, params, 'T-SQL statement'` before the calls to `sp_execute` are executed. You need to also capture the "SQL:Prepare" event in order to see what statements are being submitted. But I am not sure if you get to see the returned **handle** (i.e. the statement_id) that is then passed in as the first parameter to `sp_execute` (example: the `2` in `exec sp_execute 2,...`). The **handle** is per each Connection / Session, so **handle** of `2` for Session 53 is not necessarily the same as **handle** of `2` for Session 78. Meaning, you need to match the session_id / SPID between calls to `sp_prepare` and `sp_execute`.

Please see the following documentation:

- [sp_prepare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-prepare-transact-sql)
- [sp_execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-transact-sql)

Comment: Each sp_execute  have 1 sp_prepare? And that represent 1 sql query?(like select/update/delete)?

Comment: No, the statement can be a batch of statements. And the handle can be executed any number of times.

Comment: So I'm not understand from your replay how do I get the full query from sp_execute

Comment: You need to set up the profiler session to capture the `SQL:Prepare` event, then keep track of them, along with the SPID, ConnectionID, and TextData columns.. it will be in the TextData column. But you can't go back and get those events if they have already happened. You can just catch the next ones.

Comment: I not sure of I saw SQL:Prepare on sqlserver profiller 2012 but I will check it.  After I catch all is there a way to auto translate it to simple sql queries? That not comfortable to look each time on lot of that events